# Bind close and open function to all dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I try to bind default open and close functions to all dialogs with following ways, however none is working.

```
  $(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function(event, ui) {            
  }); 
  $(document).on("dialogclose", ".ui-dialog", function(event, ui) {   
  });
```

or

```
  $(".ui-dialog").bind("open", function() {
  });
  $(".ui-dialog").bind("close", function() {
  });
```

Do you have any idea, what is wrong here?
Thanks for your help.

Edit:

I add this function to document ready function.

Comment: My guess is that the plugin prevents these events from bubbling up to the document.

Comment: you have to assign it to the element fwhich is used to trigger the dialog, not the helper class

Comment: seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9GRZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes that all your dialogs container has `.ui-dialog-selector` class on them. this way you can select all the dialogs.

```
$(".ui-dialog-selector").bind("dialogopen", function() {
    alert('OPen');
});
```

Similarly you have to bind close

```
$(".ui-dialog-selector").bind("dialogclose", function() {
    alert('Close dialog');
});
```

**UPDATE**

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CytJf/1/)

In the demo, you can see, I have 2 dialogs created with div id one and with div id two.
Both these div have classes `ui-dialog-selector` on it.

```
<div class ='ui-dialog-selector' id ="one" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value ="open one"/>
</div>

<div class ='ui-dialog-selector' id ="two" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value ="open two"/>
</div>
```

And then I bind the functions as I have shown above.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. Did you try this code? maybe I have another problem.

Comment: I have tested this and it works. Look at the js fiddle example i have posted

Comment: try and compare how your code is different from what I have posted in here.

Answer (score 1):

**for open**

```
$(".ui-dialog").bind("dialogopen", function() {
    alert('Open');
});
```

**for close**

```
$(".ui-dialog").bind("dialogclose", function() {
    alert('Close');
});
```